# Excel 2013 - VBA - Runtime Error 9 when creating & accessing [more than 4!] Conditional Formatting Items

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched and searched and not come up with a solution and cannot explain what is happening.

Basically I have a worksheet in Excel 2013 that has a selection of invoicing data on each row.  The worksheet has 8 conditional formats on it at various ranges.

As rows get inserted [at the top of the range] in to the range using this approach:

```
    Manager.Select
    Manager.Range("headerRow").Offset(1, 0).Range("a1:M1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

the conditional formatting gets convoluted, messy, fragmented and eventually after a few months is such a mess it seems stops working correctly.

After wasting several hours on various approaches my solution is simple. (SURE!)  When a row gets inserted at the top of the range then I want to clear and reset the 8 x conditional formats using VBA - in essence perform a quick clean-up - by deleting all of the the conditional formatting on the worksheet and reapplying 8 clean conditional formats with the correct ranges and formatting for the entire range (top to bottom).

The problem is that after adding and formatting 4 conditional formats using .FormatConditions.Add and .FormatConditions(x) it throws a Subscript Error when I attempt to format the Item 5 Font or background color.  I have searched for an explanation and understand that basically I can add as many CF's as I like so what is going on?

The crazy thing is that it appeared to work correctly once then never again?

Here is my test code and it all works well until formula 5!

```
Sub CFReset()

' Get top and bottom of Invoices
TopRow = (Manager.Range("headerRow").Row) + 1
BottomRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

' Clear All Current Conditional Formatting on Manager Sheet between Invoice Top Row and Invocie Bottom Row
Range("A" & TopRow & ":L" & BottomRow).FormatConditions.Delete

'CD Formula 1 - 'Formula:  =AND(I17="Paid",G17<>0) - 'Colour: Red on White Background 'Applies to: =$G$17:$G$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$G$" & TopRow & ":$G$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(I" & TopRow & "=""Paid"",G" & TopRow & "<>0)"
    .FormatConditions(1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
End With

'CD Formula 2 - '=AND(I17="Partial",F17<>0) 'Colour: Red on white background 'Applies to: =$G$17:$G$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$G$" & TopRow & ":$G$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(I" & TopRow & "=""Partial"",F" & TopRow & "<>0)"
    .FormatConditions(2).Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
End With

'CD Formula 3 '=OR($I17="Void") - Text Colour RGB: 255,179,179 'Applies to: =$A$17:$I$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$" & TopRow & ":$I$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR($I" & TopRow & "=""Void"")"
    .FormatConditions(3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 179, 179) ' Pinkish
End With

'CD Formula 4 - '=OR($I17="Paid",$I17="Closed") - Text Colour: RGB 192, 192, 192 'Applies to: =$A$17:$I$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$" & TopRow & ":$I$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR($I" & TopRow & "=""Paid"",$I" & TopRow & "=""Closed"")"
    .FormatConditions(4).Font.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) ' Gray
End With

'CD Formula 5 '=AND(I17="Paid",G17<>0) 'Color: RGB 0, 0, 0 'Black 'Background Colour:RGB: 255,255,204 ' Light Yellow 'Applies to: =$F$17:$F$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$F$" & TopRow & ":$F$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(I" & TopRow & "=""Paid"",G" & TopRow & "<>0)"
    .FormatConditions(5).Font.ColorIndex = 1 ' Black
    .FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204) ' Light Yellow
End With

'CD Formula 6  '=AND(I17="Partial",F17=0) 'Color: RGB 0, 0, 0 'Black 'Background Colour:RGB: 255,255,204 ' Light Yellow 'Applies to: =$F$17:$F$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$F$" & TopRow & ":$F$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(I" & TopRow & "=""Partial"",F" & TopRow & "=0)"
    .FormatConditions(6).Font.ColorIndex = 1 ' Black
    .FormatConditions(6).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204) ' Light Yellow
End With


'CD Formula 7 '=AND(G17>0,AND(D17<TODAY(),D17<>"")) 'Colour: Red 'Background Colour:RGB: 255,255,204 ' Light Yellow 'Applies to: =$D$17:$D$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$D$" & TopRow & ":$D$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(G" & TopRow & ">0,AND(D" & TopRow & "<TODAY(),D" & TopRow & "<>""""))"
    .FormatConditions(7).Font.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
    .FormatConditions(7).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204) ' Light Yellow
End With


'CD Formula 8 '=COUNTIF($B:$B,B17)>1 'Color: RGB 255,255,255 -'White 'Background Colour: Red ' Rgb 255 ' Applies to: =$B$17:$B$49
With ActiveSheet.Range("$B$" & TopRow & ":$B$" & BottomRow)
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF($B:$B,B" & TopRow & ")>1"
    .FormatConditions(8).Font.ColorIndex = 2 ' White
    .FormatConditions(8).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 ' Red
End With


End Sub
```

If I rem out the formatting of font and background the CF rule is added to the worksheet but clearly this is a waste of time without formatting! :)

I also attempted a different way of formatting the font color Background color however selecting a Conditional Formatting item higher than 4 returns the same error.

```
'Attempt2
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$" & TopRow & ":$I$" & BottomRow).FormatConditions
    .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR($I" & TopRow & "=""Void"")"
    With .Item(3).Font
        .Color = RGB(255, 179, 179) ' Pinkish
    End With
End With
```

I have included my remarks which are my notes for each of the formats - these are actually from my original CF's.

Comment: If you hid row 2 and started all of the data input on row 3 with the CF rules' *Applies to:* starting at row 2, wouldn't inserting a new row at row 3 (pushing everything down) auto-magically adjust the applies to?

Comment: One note and one suggestion. Note that when adding a new CF condition it becomes `FormatConditions(1)`. You are effectively modifying the same one over and over, I think. I also suggest you look at the the`.FormatConditions.ModifyAppliesToRange` method. This allows you to adjust the range the FormatCondition applies to. (I suppose that's obvious!)

Comment: @ Jeeped Yes your suggestion is in theory great however it would require altering many many lines of code elsewhere so not really an option. @Doug - Each of the CF's is different formatting and various ranges based on differing conditions and since adding rows etc mucks up the stored CF's  I thought it would be super easy to clean them out then reapply.   I just CAN'T figure out why the above coding(s) do not work and returns the error?

Comment: Anyone have ANY thoughts why it would get to CF item 5 then error? This one has really driven me crazy

Comment: I understand your problem. Did you understand either of my points? Your response gives no indication whether you do.Good luck!

Comment: Hi Doug, yes thanks - sorry for not being clear? - I reviewed ModifyAppliesToRange however this still relies on the CF index and I'm not sure how to implement the command to apply text and background color?  MSDN isn't very clear on this and I haven't seen it before.  I  thought my "simple" solution was clever and it should have done the trick.

Comment: Ok. How about fixing the indexes? Again, each time you add a condition it becomes FormatConditionds(1). You keep modifying your first added condition over and over, eight times.

Comment: Okay, I just realized I'm wrong, because I left out a step, which is adding the `FormatConditions.SetFirstPriority` statement. When you do that, **then** the last condition you added is #1, making it less painful to track them. Try running the Macro Recorder and adding a couple of conditional formats. When you look at the resulting code you'll see what I mean. Sorry about that.

Comment: ...Or see my comment on BarrowC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `FormatConditions` collection relates to the range you specify and not to the whole worksheet. Your conditional format #5 is breaking because it only applies to part of column F and there have only been two previous CFs defined which include that part of column F. If you changed your reference into the collection from `.FormatConditions(5)` to `.FormatConditions(3)` then it should work

CFs #1 and #2 only applied to part of column G whereas CFs #3 and #4 applied to parts of columns A:I. So when you try to add CF #5 to part of column F, there are only two previous CFs in the collection. To fix this, CF #5 should use index 3, CF #6 should use index 4, CF #7 should use index 3 and CF #8 should use index 3

Comment: Alternately, you could just do `.FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)`, which would be flexible. +1

Comment: Thanks Doug!  You are correct!  After some guidance on Mr Excel I rearranged the CF's and put the Global CF's first THEN the others.  I was also directed to use .FormatConditions.Count instead if the CF Index # - It worked perfect first time thanks to AlphaFrog!   See here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/838576-excel-2013-visual-basic-applications-runtime-error-9-when-creating-accessing-%5Bmore-than-4-%5D-conditional-formating-items-help-please.html#post4086241  Many thanks for all your efforts!

Comment: I'm glad we got there eventually. :)